# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 6952: invalid start byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am getting an error for the code I have pasted below. I tried to look for similar questions on the forum and honestly, I did find a few with the same issue. However, some of then did not have solutions yet and the ones which had solutions did not work for my case(atleast I could not make it work). Pasting the code snippet as below:

```
# coding: utf-8

# In[14]:


import csv
import datetime
import re
import codecs
import requests
import pandas as pd
#import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
import numpy as np


def get_google_finance_intraday(ticker, period=60, days=20, exchange='NSE'):

    # build url
    url = 'https://finance.google.com/finance/getprices' +     '?p={days}d&f=d,o,h,l,c,v&q={ticker}&i={period}&x={exchange}'.format(ticker=ticker, 
                                                                           period=period, 
                                                                           days=days,
                                                                           exchange=exchange)

    page = requests.get(url)
    reader = csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(page.content.splitlines(), "utf-8"))
    columns = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
    rows = []
    times = []
    for row in reader:
        if re.match('^[a\d]', row[0]):
            if row[0].startswith('a'):
                start = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(row[0][1:]))
                times.append(start)
            else:
                times.append(start+datetime.timedelta(seconds=period*int(row[0])))
            rows.append(map(float, row[1:]))
    if len(rows):
        return pd.DataFrame(rows, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(times, name='Date'), columns=columns)
    else:
        return pd.DataFrame(rows, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(times, name='Date'))

i = 0
with open('1.0.Ticker_names -MasterCopy.csv') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in csvreader:
        symbol_name = row
        symbol = "".join(map(str, symbol_name))

        # input data
        ticker = symbol
        period = 60
        days = 200
        exchange = 'NSE'

       df = get_google_finance_intraday(ticker, period=period, days=days)


        ohlc_dict = {                                                                                                             
        'Open':'first',                                                                                                    
        'High':'max',                                                                                                       
        'Low':'min',                                                                                                        
        'Close': 'last',                                                                                                    
        'Volume': 'sum'
        }

        df = df.resample('60MIN',base=15).apply(ohlc_dict).dropna(how='any')
        df['Name'] = ticker

        df.to_csv(ticker+'.csv')
```

The csv file - 1.0.Ticker_names -MasterCopy.csv only has names of the stock in column A with names starting from cell "A1".

I am getting the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Downloads\0-Copy1.0.Final_Intraday Stock     data_v0.1_22June2018 (2).py", line 80, in <module>
    df = get_google_finance_intraday(ticker, period=period, days=days)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Downloads\0-Copy1.0.Final_Intraday Stock     data_v0.1_22June2018 (2).py", line 54, in get_google_finance_intraday
    for row in reader:
  File     "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\codecs.py", line     1041, in iterdecode
    output = decoder.decode(input)
  File     "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\codecs.py", line     321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position     6952: invalid start byte
```

Comment: tried including encoding parameter in to_csv() ?

Comment: @Harikrishna - I am absolutely new to any sort of coding or tech. I am not sure what you mean but did you mean to_csv(ticker+'.csv', utf-8)?

Comment: df.to_csv(ticker+'.csv',encoding='utf-8)

Comment: @Harikrishna - I tried, but did not work. Still the same error!

Comment: Are you sure your data is utf-8 encoded?  Try `df.to_csv(f'{ticker}.csv', encoding='latin1')` (which is often found on windows)

Comment: @Thtu - still doesn;'t work

Comment: You may want to try to brute force it with "encoding=ISO-8859-1", some potential for character loss on strings but ints/floats should be ok.

Comment: @MichaelB - still no luck man! same error!